# Accessing a member type of an incomplete type

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

What is the workaround to get this to compile?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Derived>
struct CRTP {
    void foo (const typename Derived::type& a) {std::cout << a << '\n';}
};

struct A : CRTP<A> {
    using type = int;
};

struct B : CRTP<B> {
    using type = std::string;
};

// etc...

int main() {
    A a;
    a.foo(5);
}
```

This will not compile, because at the time of instantiation of `CRTP<A>`, `A` isn't a complete class yet, so `A::type` cannot be accessed.  But what is the workaround?  I need this type of design so that the foo function can be used generically for many different classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't use the CRTP on a 'using' case. You can use it for methods and members, but not things like types. When using templates though, having types as template parameters is what it is so useful for, so why not do

```
template <typename Derived, typename Type>
....
```

Which will work perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, nice simple solution that I simply didn't think of.  I suspect it is the only solution too.

Answer (score 4):

A somewhat crazier alternative is to defer evaluation until an attempt is made to call `foo`, by which point `Derived` would be complete. This requires making it a template.

```
template <typename Derived>
struct CRTP {
    template<class T = Derived>
    void foo (const typename T::type& a) {std::cout << a << '\n';}
};
```

It is trivial to block calling `foo` with a type that isn't `Derived`, if desired, via a `static_assert`.

Comment: It very much will compile.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. It compiles because it doesn't attempt to deduce the template parameter from the argument. Will remove that comment, I just checked to confirm your response.

Comment: FWIW, this is the kind of issue I was expecting to happen, but your answer doesn't have this issue because as I said, the template parameter is not deduced from the argument. https://godbolt.org/z/4xTvEzr4a